# Auto Re-run Script in case of crash

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a small .bat script which I run on a shared server.  In it, I just call python and run a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
@echo off
python SCRIPT.py
```

In the python script, I am pulling data repeatedly from a website every minute or so.  For some reason the API connection isn't great and every once in a while (maybe after an hour or two of data pulling), it throws an error like "connection timed out".

To remedy this, I want to just loop back every time the python script breaks out;

```
#!/bin/bash
@echo off
:loop
python SCRIPT.py
goto loop
```

Given my lack of understanding of this stuff, I just want to know if this will actually work in re-running the python script *only* *after* the previous one error-ed out.

Comment: That is not bash, that is batch. Not the same thing!

Comment: Have you considered handling this problem in the python script? It would most likely give you greater control and would avoid adding a language you don't master to the mix.